# Не срабатывает повторное сохранение в файл word из программы C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

Есть код, который из `DataTable` и полей формы создает вордовский документ на основе определенного шаблона. Но почему-то после повторного нажатия на кнопку сохранения вылетает ошибка "ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" на строчке кода:

```
document = application.Documents.Add(ref templatePathObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
```

Некоторые переменные пришлось объявить глобально, т.к. они почему-то не распознавались в блоке `try`-`catch`, если объявлять их локально.
Полный код функции:

```
DataTable dt_fasad = new DataTable();

Word._Document document;
Word._Application application = new Word.Application();
Object trueObj = true;
Object falseObj = false;
object missingObj = Missing.Value;
object templatePathObj;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //открытие файла
    try
    {
        string documentpath = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\act.docx";
        missingObj = Missing.Value;
        templatePathObj = documentpath;
        document = application.Documents.Add(ref templatePathObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);

        //заполнение закладок
        object bookmarkObj_fio = "z1";
        object bookmarkObj_fioCopy = "z3";
        object bookmarkObj_unp = "z2";
        object bookmarkObj_adres = "z4";
        object bookmarkObj_rs = "z6";
        object bookmarkObj_sum = "z7";
        object bookmarkObj_data = "zData";

        Word.Range bookmarkRange_fio = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_fio).Range;
        Word.Range bookmarkRange_fioCopy = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_fioCopy).Range;
        Word.Range bookmarkRange_unp = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_unp).Range;
        Word.Range bookmarkRange_adres = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_adres).Range;
        Word.Range bookmarkRange_rs = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_rs).Range;
        Word.Range bookmarkRange_sum = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_sum).Range;
        Word.Range bookmarkRange_data = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref bookmarkObj_data).Range;

        //Указываем содержимое закладок
        bookmarkRange_fio.Text = textBox2.Text;
        bookmarkRange_unp.Text = textBox3.Text;
        bookmarkRange_fioCopy.Text = textBox2.Text;
        bookmarkRange_fioCopy.Bold = 1;
        bookmarkRange_adres.Text = textBox5.Text;
        bookmarkRange_rs.Text = textBox4.Text;
        bookmarkRange_data.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");

        double summ = 0;
        //Получаем проведенные работы
        var dtres = dt_fasad.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(t => new
           {
               Id = t.Field<int>("Картридж")
           })
           .Select(g => new
           {
               g.Key.Id,
               Value = String.Join(", ", g.Select(i => i.Field<string>("Проведенные_работы")))
           }).ToList();

        var sumres = dt_fasad.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(t => new
           {
               Id = t.Field<int>("Картридж")
           })
           .Select(g => new
           {
               g.Key.Id,
               Value = g.Sum(s => (s.Field<double>("Общая_цена")))
           }).ToList();

        var res2 =
            from r in dt_fasad.AsEnumerable()
            group r by r["Марка"] into g
            select new
            {
                p = g.Key
            };

        //работа с таблицей
        int ik = 2;
        int ir = 2;
        Word.Table _table = document.Tables[1]; //Выбрать уже существующую таблицу внутри документа можно по ее порядковому номеру (начиная с 1 и начала документа)
        _table.AllowAutoFit = true;

        foreach (var zap in dtres)
        {
            _table.Rows.Add(ref missingObj);
            Word.Range _currentRange = _table.Cell(ik, 3).Range;
            Word.Range _currentRangeNumb = _table.Cell(ik, 1).Range;
            Word.Range _currentRangeId = _table.Cell(ik, 2).Range;

            _currentRange.Text = zap.Value.ToString();
            _currentRangeNumb.Text = Convert.ToString(ik - 1);
            _currentRangeId.Text = zap.Id.ToString();
            _table.Rows[ik].SetHeight(35, Word.WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightAuto);
            ik++;
        }

        foreach (var sumchik in sumres)
        {
            Word.Range _currentRangeCena = _table.Cell(ir, 4).Range;
            Word.Range _currentRangeCenaNoNDS = _table.Cell(ir, 5).Range;
            Word.Range _currentRangeNDS = _table.Cell(ir, 6).Range;
            Word.Range _currentRangeSummaNDS = _table.Cell(ir, 7).Range;
            Word.Range _currentRangeCenaNDS = _table.Cell(ir, 8).Range;

            _currentRangeCena.Text = Math.Round(sumchik.Value, 2).ToString();
            _currentRangeCenaNoNDS.Text = Math.Round(sumchik.Value, 2).ToString();
            summ += Math.Round(sumchik.Value, 2);
            _currentRangeNDS.Text = "Без НДС";
            _currentRangeSummaNDS.Text = "-";
            _currentRangeCenaNDS.Text = Math.Round(sumchik.Value, 2).ToString();
            ir++;

        }
        _table.Rows.Add(ref missingObj);
        _table.Rows[ik].Height = 15;
        _table.Columns[1].SetWidth(25, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional);
        _table.Columns[2].SetWidth(40, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional);
        _table.Columns[3].SetWidth(200, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional);
        _table.Columns[4].SetWidth(30, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional);
        _table.Columns[5].SetWidth(55, Word.WdRulerStyle.wdAdjustProportional);

        _table.Rows[ik].Cells[2].Merge(_table.Rows[ik].Cells[3]);

        Word.Range _currentObsh = _table.Cell(ik, 2).Range;
        Word.Range _currentCenaObs = _table.Cell(ik, 3).Range;
        Word.Range _currentCenaNoNDS = _table.Cell(ik, 4).Range;
        Word.Range _currentNDSProc = _table.Cell(ik, 5).Range;
        Word.Range _currentSumNDS = _table.Cell(ik, 6).Range;
        Word.Range _currentSOBSHSUm = _table.Cell(ik, 7).Range;

        _currentObsh.Text = "Итого";
        _currentObsh.Bold = 1;

        _currentCenaObs.Text = Math.Round(summ, 2).ToString();
        _currentCenaNoNDS.Text = Math.Round(summ, 2).ToString();
        _currentNDSProc.Text = "x";
        _currentSumNDS.Text = "-";
        _currentSOBSHSUm.Text = Math.Round(summ, 2).ToString();


        //регистрируем новую валюту - белорусский рубль (BYN)
        RusCurrency.Register("BYN", true, "белорусский рубль", "белорусских рубля", "белорусских рублей", "копейка", "копейки", "копеек");

        //С числом работаем
        bookmarkRange_sum.Text = RusCurrency.Str(summ, "BYN");
        bookmarkRange_sum.Bold = 1;

        //
        //Вывод на печать
        //document.PrintOut(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "act_na_pechat";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".docx";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Word Documents|*.docx";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            document.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
        ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj,
        ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        }
        document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        application.Quit();
        document = null;
        application = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Текст ошибки: "+ ex.Message);
        document.Close(ref falseObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        application.Quit(ref missingObj, ref missingObj, ref missingObj);
        document = null;
        application = null;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я мог допустить ошибку. Первый раз работаю с word и по коду должно быть понятно, что нахватался всего по чуть-чуть где только возможно)

Comment: Ставьте breakpoint на этой строчке и через local view глядите что у Вас ==null

Comment: во вкладке "видимые" после первого клика только document = null. Во вкладке "локальные" все мои закладки =null. После второго клика закладки все равно null, а вот document = {Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass}.

Comment: Хм, а может быть такое, что я создавал объект один раз глобально, затем, после нажатия на кнопку, этот объект "убивался" и уже второй раз не мог быть вызван. Сейчас в блоке try прописал application = new Word.Application(); и вроде как работает... Только правильно ли это?)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не делать вот это

```
document = null;
application = null;
```

Единственное что пока могу сказать

Comment: Теперь на той же самой строке ошибка Сервер RPC недоступен. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Answer (score 0):

То что мне помогло так это убить старый Application, и создать новый

```
_application.Quit();
_application = new Application();
```